# how to start the api gateway when starting a js-ipfs node?

Tags: ipfs

When a js-ipfs node is started programatically using the below code in *node.js* app, it is launching the swarm, allowing to add files and query them back.

```
// code from the docs: https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#use-in-nodejs

const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const node = new IPFS()

node.on('ready', () => {
  // Ready to use!
})
```

But the API and gateway are not available, which means the web-ui is not available to inspect the repo contents. How to start the API gateway along with ipfs swarm using the `ipfs` npm package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, posting here to help anyone looking for similar info.

The API gateway is available as `http` module inside the `ipfs`, which can be invoked as shown below on start of the ipfs node:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const node = new IPFS()

node.on('ready', () => {
   // start the API gateway
    const Gateway = require('ipfs/src/http');
    const gateway = new Gateway(node);
    return gateway.start();
})
```

The API and Gateway will be listening on the ports specified in the config that is used in the `new IPFS()`, which can be edited from the `repo/config` file location or supplied programatically, such as:

```
  "Addresses": {
    "API": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
    "Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080"
  }
```

Comment: This is correct, however, we don't recommend requiring internals directly (it is an antipattern). Instead, check out https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfsd-ctl/, it lets you spawn all kinds of daemons and nodes :)

Comment: thank  you @DavidDias The `ipfsd-ctl` looks more like spwaning a whole different process altogether. If we have node started already with the `ipfs` package (as shown in my code above), would the gateway started with the `ipfsd-ctl` be still interacting with the node that is already started, or spawns a brand-new node and gateway combo together. More importantly, the reason for starting a node with `ipfs` package is to control the `datastore` (with customized repo functionality). I am not sure if `ipfsd-ctl` would be providing the gateway for my node (with custom datastore node) in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

TCP ports with [HTTP API](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/) and Gateway are opened when running js-ipfs as a daemon (Node.js):

```
$ jsipfs daemon
(...)
Gateway (read only) listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/9090/http
Web UI available at http://127.0.0.1:5002/webui
Daemon is ready
```

JavaScript running in regular web browser is unable to open TCP ports so js-ipfs running on a web page does not expose HTTP API and Gateway.

You need to use [programmatic interface](https://github.com/ipfs/interface-js-ipfs-core/tree/master/SPEC) to interact with it.

Comment: Thank you @lidel . The question was more about programmatic use of `ipfs` package than CLI. Sorry about the confusion. Added more clarity to the question. Also, found an answer and  posted it below. Thank you .